# "unmet dependencies" error when trying to install gnuradio on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Following the guide here:

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR#Ubuntu_PPA_Installation

I attempt install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-master
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gnuradio
```

My output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnuradio : Depends: libgnuradio-analog (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not     going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-audio (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-blocks (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-channels (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-digital (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-dtv (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-fec (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-fft (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-filter (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-qtgui (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-runtime (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-trellis (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-uhd (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-video-sdl (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-vocoder (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-wavelet (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgnuradio-zeromq (>= 3.9.0.0git~master~13593~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: python3-qwt-qt5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I go up the dependency chain with one of the error packages I finally get:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnuradio-runtime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnuradio-runtime : Depends: libvolk2.2 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get install libvolk2.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libvolk2.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libvolk2.2' has no installation candidate
```

Looking up libvolk2.2 indicates it is in Debian's sid (unstable) repository.  However when I search about installing gnuradio, I do not find anything mentioned about having to use sid repositories.  And also it would seem if that were the case, the guide I used would mention that.

So before resorting to using sid repositories and risking breakage, I would like to see if there is some other thing I am not seeing that is needed.

Thanks kindly for any help.

Help would be much appreciated.

[EDIT] Would like to mention also that this is a fresh install of 18.04, and AFAICT the auto software updater has everything up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-master
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.7
> ```

You need to add only one of the above PPA repositories and not all three.

> So before resorting to using sid repositories and risking breakage, I would like to see if there is some other thing I am not seeing that is needed.

Yes, the packages in `ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-master` currently seems to be broken. I just successfully installed gnuradio 3.8 from the `ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases` repository.

First you need to remove the `ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases` and `ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.7` and then retry installing `gnuradio`

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnuradio-ubuntu-gnuradio-master-bionic.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnuradio-ubuntu-gnuradio-releases-3_7-bionic.list
apt-get install gnuradio
```

Comment: Yup, the volk dependencies weren't updated: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/3267#issuecomment-600112613.  They should be updated by now.  This only affects master builds, and it turns out I didn't need any of the PPAs at all for installing the release build.  I removed them all and the install went fine.